# why can't console.log print with backward order index [-1]

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, console.log

i am new with JavaScript. Pls help.

I was playing with the method - console.log. here is what i did:

```
let iceCreamFlavors = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla", "Pistachio", "Neapolitan", "Mint Chip"];
delete iceCreamFlavors[iceCreamFlavors.length-1];
console.log(iceCreamFlavors[length-1])
```

the console came back with

```
undefined
```

if I do:

`console.log(iceCreamFlavors[5])`

it has no problem to print

```
Mint Chip
```

but if I do:

```
console.log(iceCreamFlavors[-1])
```

it came back with

```
undefined
```

so my question is why can't console.log work with index numbers in the backward order?
Maybe there is not much use in reality, but I am just curious.

Comment: Where did you set the variable `length`?

Comment: `console.log(iceCreamFlavors[-1])` because arrays do not reference from the end when it is negative....

Comment: `iceCreamFlavors [length-1]` should be `iceCreamFlavors [iceCreamFlavors.length-1]`

Comment: I didn't set it. Isn't length a built-in method?

Comment: @annazhwj Only if you use it as a property after an object.

Comment: okay. let me try....thanks.

Comment: You did it correctly in the `delete` call, you made the mistake in `console.log`

Comment: Look at @Barmar 's answer.  If you just put length, how does javascript know what object you are talking about?  length needs to be off of the object.  iceCreateFlavors.length

Comment: JavaScript is not like Python, it doesn't treat negative indexes as counting from the end, except in a few methods like `substr()`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. i will remember your advice for other occasions, even though it still doesn't work in this case.

Comment: It should work. It should print `Neapolitan`, since you deleted `Mint Chip`.

Comment: @epascarello thanks. i think what you said should explain. I better simply create reference from left to right. I tried: console.log(iceCreamFlavors[-1])and [-2], it didn't work.

Comment: @annazhwj because that is not how it works in JavaScript. It is looking at the -1 property of the object.

Comment: @Barmar I did this -  console.log(iceCreamFlavors[iceCreamFlavors.length-2]). and it came back with - Neapolitan. so I guess when -1 is empty, it can only show "undefined". good learning. Thanks : )

Comment: @annazhwj check my answer, i explained it a bit

Comment: @Barmar i mentioned it in my answer :D

Comment: `var x = [1,2,3]; x[-1] = "-1 property"; console.log(x[-1]); console.log(x[x.length-1]);` if you want to get rid of the last index, use `x.pop();` using delete you end up with `[1, 2, undefined]` with pop() you would have `[1, 2]`

Comment: it's not that the `deleted` index is empty, you have actually removed that index from the accessible properties of the array.

Comment: @Barmar embarrasing. you are very correct. I was careless just now. i tried console.log(iceCreamFlavors[iceCreamFlavors.length-1]) again, it actually printed "empty". so the case was ultimately resolved. it worked! thanks!

Comment: @AnanthDev thanks!

Comment: @epascarello with delete you end up with `[ 1, 2, <1 empty item> ]`, not `[ 1, 2, undefined ]`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` keyword is used to delete `Object` properties and not array elements, to remove an array element use `Array.prototype.filter()` or `Array.prototype.splice()`

Splice will modify the original array while filter will return a new array which passes the condition specified in callback.

```js
let iceCreamFlavors = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla", "Pistachio", "Neapolitan", "Mint Chip"];
iceCreamFlavors.splice(5, 1);
console.log(iceCreamFlavors);
```

```js
let iceCreamFlavors = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla", "Pistachio", "Neapolitan", "Mint Chip"];
const filter = iceCreamFlavors.filter(x => x != 'Mint Chip');
console.log(filter);
```

**Note**: you can access array elements using `array[index]`, the index has a range from `0 to array.length - 1`. Arrays starts from 0 index, which means first element will have index 0 and second will have index 1 so on

```js
let iceCreamFlavors = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla", "Pistachio", "Neapolitan", "Mint Chip"];
iceCreamFlavors.splice(5, 1);
console.log(iceCreamFlavors.length); // array length
console.log(iceCreamFlavors[iceCreamFlavors.length - 1]); // last element
console.log(iceCreamFlavors[0]); // first element
```

****delete vs splice in array****

delete will not change the length or reindex the array, the given element is removed but it is appeared as `undefined`

splice will completely remove the element along with changing the length and reindex the elements